# Why I need to verify Steam file integrity when a play Civilization V in DX9 mode?

Tags: civilization-5, steam

In order to play Civilization V in DX9 mode I have to verify the file integrity, and Steam downloads a file.

Any idea why I have to do this in order to play?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just a feature to ensure that downloaded files are not corrupt and is usually used to attempt and troubleshoot major glitches that could be caused by corrupt files. Are you having an issue? If so add more detail and I will attempt to update my answer with more information.

EDIT: Try disabling UAC, I had an issue where Risen would not activate with the product key when UAC was enabled at even the 2nd to lowest level, had to disable it entirely.

Comment: The issue is that I can't play without verifying first...

Comment: @TheX Every single time? I.e., even after verification has completed successfully once?

Comment: Steam should verify a file once (and only once) after it has downloaded, this protects your computer from using a corrupt or damaged files. If you find they steam is trying to verify it each time, either delete/re-install the game/steam or post a bug report to steam.

Comment: @TheX see my edit

Comment: I will give that a try.